# graphqlj-js union type, access args

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql-js

I'm trying to figure out how to access the `args` field of `retrieveRowsWithoutLocations`. However, I'm not even sure what goes into the `value` parameter in the `resolveType` function of UnionType.

I'm looking at the documentation https://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqluniontype but it's quite brief and doesn't go into detail where that information is picked up from. I've tried looking at other sources but they aren't graphql-js.

What I'm trying to do is access `args.type` and check its value, which then allows the union to decide which type it should return.

```
let rows_union =
    new graphql.GraphQLUnionType({
        name: 
            "rows_union",
        types: 
        [
            many_item,
            many_list,
            many_display_list, 
        ],
        resolveType(value) 
        {
            switch(value)
            {
                case "item":
                    return many_item
                case "list":
                    return many_list
                case "display_list":
                    return many_display_list
            }
        }
    })

// Define the Query type
var query =
    new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
        name: "Query",
        fields:
        {
            retrieveRowsWithoutLocations:
            {
                type:
                    rows_union,
                args:
                {
                    _id:
                    {
                        type:
                            nonNullId()
                    },
                    page:
                    {
                        type:
                            nonNullInt()
                    },
                    page_length:
                    {
                        type:
                            nonNullInt()
                    },
                    type:
                    {
                        type:
                            nonNullString()
                    },
                },
                async resolve ()
                {

                }
            },
        }
    })
```

```
let many_type =
    new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
        name: "many_"+name,
        fields: {
            results: {
                type: graphql.GraphQLList(type)
            },
            total: {
                type: graphql.GraphQLNonNull(graphql.GraphQLInt)
            },
        }
    })
```

`type` is another ObjectType

Comment: Can you include the code for `many_item`,` many_list`, and `many_display_list`?

Comment: @DanielRearden no need... they're just object types. You can easily pretend they're `Int`, `String` or `Float` and it wouldn't matter...

Comment: I can't do that because scalars can't be used inside a union :P I wanted to look at that code to cater my answer to your specific use-case

Comment: @DanielRearden I added it in, but I don't think there's any point to it since I'm asking about accessing the `args` in a query/mutation, which doesn't seem to work since the `resolveType` function is actually reading the result. I'm going to split it into multiple queries instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly access any resolver parameters inside `resolveType` (or `isTypeOf`). When a field is resolved, the resolver returns some value, or a Promise that will resolve to that value. In the case of a field that returns an output type, interface or union, this value should be a JavaScript object. It's this value that is then passed to `resolveType`, which is used to determine what type is actually being returned in the response at runtime.

Given a schema like

```
union Animal = Bird | Fish

type Bird {
  numberOfWings: Int
}

type Fish {
  numberOfFins: Int
}

type Query {
  animal: Animal
}
```

you can image that the resolver for the `animal` field returns JavaScript objects like `{ numberOfWings: 2 }` `{ numberOfFins: 4 }`. Here, we could utilize a simple heuristic to determine the type:

```
resolveType: (value) => {
  if (value.numberOfWings !== undefined) {
    return 'Bird'
  } else if (value.numberOfFins !== undefined) {
    return 'Fish'
  }
  throw new TypeError(`Unable to resolve type for Animal with value: ${value}`)
}
```

If instead of returning simple objects, we return instances of specific classes, we can do even better:

```
resolveType: (value) => {
  if (value instanceof BirdModel) {
    return 'Bird'
  } else if (value instanceof FishModel) {
    return 'Fish'
  }
  throw new TypeError(`Unable to resolve type for Animal with value: ${value}`)
}
```

Whatever our conditional logic looks like, just remember that we're always just testing the value being returned by the resolver, whatever that happens to be.

Things get a bit trickier if you're not using classes and two or more of the types share the same structure. Or, as in your case, when the distinguishing property (`results`) is an array, since inspecting one of the elements is a no-go. Imagine our union instead looks like this:

```
union Animal = Cat | Dog

type Cat {
  numberOfPaws: Int
}

type Dog {
  numberOfPaws: Int
}
```

Here, unfortunately, we have to rely on our resolver to provide some additional information. For example, we could return some arbitrary field to identify the type:

```
// Resolver for animal field
resolve: () => {
  return {
    numberOfPaws: 4,
    kind: 'Dog',
  }
}

// Union
resolveType: (value) => {
  return value.kind
}
```

But we can actually do one better by relying on the default implementations of `resolveType` and `isTypeOf`:

```
resolve: () => {
  return {
    numberOfPaws: 4,
    __typename: 'Dog',
  }
}
```

By explicitly returning the `__typename` like this, we can actually **omit defining `resolveType` altogether**. However, keep in mind that, again, this creates a dependency on the resolver. Where possible, you should probably favor using `resolveType` with `instanceof` checks instead to decouple `resolveType` from your resolver logic.